# How to use a String Input as a Variable Call In Python?

Tags: python, variables, input

```
item =["Item_name","Price"]
stop = input("Enter your message: ")
if stop[:3] == "add":
  item2 = stop[4:]
```

I have a code something like this and I want to get the variable item based on a user input. For example, the user types inputs "add item", it should output `item[0]` and `item[1]`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask]() from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Also see [help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking it down into small pieces is the easiest way to keep it from getting out of hand when you need to add more commands -- trying to parse a command string with slices is going to get complicated quickly!  Instead, try splitting the command into words, and then associating each word with the thing you want to do with it.

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Callable, Dict

class Command(Enum):
   """All the commands the user might input."""
   ADD = "add"
   # other commands go here

class Parameter(Enum):
   """All the parameters to those commands."""
   ITEM = "item"
   # other parameters go here


item = ["Item_name","Price"]


def add_func(param: Parameter) -> None:
    """Add a thing."""
    if param == Parameter.ITEM:
        print(item)

COMMAND_FUNCS: Dict[Command, Callable[[Parameter], None]] = {
    """The functions that implement each command."""
    Command.ADD: add_func,
}

# Get the command and parameter from the user,
# and then run that function with that parameter!
[cmd, param] = input("Enter your message: ").split()
COMMAND_FUNCS[Command(cmd)](Parameter(param))
```